# Single Responsibility Principle and Many methods in Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-responsibility-principle

I am trying to understand the Single-Responsibility Principle (SRP). It says a class should have only one responsibility and reason to change. This is a typical Repository below. Does that mean, each item should be its own class? Currently Insert, Delete, Search, are all in 1 class? If that's the case, why don't people separate all the items into multiple classes?

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: The single responsibility of this class is to perform CRUD against the db

Comment: thats what I was saying, Create, Read, Update, Delete, seems like 4 items

Comment: in terms of software things like responsibility can be deemed in such a way as to suit the practicalities.  nothing stopping you from separating out into different classes - but it would be a pain to maintain

Comment: you could also say "what are the responsibilities of a repository class?" - answer "CRUD"

Comment: i wouldnt worry so much about a repository and SRP, id worry more of building another level of abstraction and complication that is already implemented for you in entity framework. It already is repository/UOW

Comment: I would rephrase what you said about SRP into being `A class should have only ONE reason to change`. The responsibility of the Repository class would be to execute operations against a database (CRUD operations for example). Many people get confused thinking that a class should only contain one method, but that's not what Robert Martin describes

Comment: if someone wants to sum up comments in answer below, that may help, thanks-

Comment: There are plenty of ways, if its just the 4 crud methods, leave them in one and that's fine. if you have update/insert/delete and many (5+) read operations, consider splitting that into a read and write repository. If you have a lot more read/write operations, consider applying CQRS with Command Handlers for each writing (insert, update, delete, bulk delete etc) operation and Query handlers for each read operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**question**: what are the responsibilities of this repository class?

**answer**  : to execute operations against a database (CRUD)

further reading: http://pragmaticcraftsman.com/2006/07/single-responsibility-principle

Answer (score 2):

"I would rephrase what you said about SRP into being. A class should have only ONE reason to change. The responsibility of the Repository class would be to execute operations against a database (CRUD operations for example). Many people get confused thinking that a class should only contain one method, but that's not what Robert Martin describes...There are plenty of ways, if its just the 4 crud methods, leave them in one and that's fine. if you have update/insert/delete and many (5+) read operations, consider splitting that into a read and write repository. If you have a lot more read/write operations, consider applying CQRS with Command Handlers for each writing (insert, update, delete, bulk delete etc) operation and Query handlers for each read operation –"